# Java LibGDX export jar with changed working directory exlipse

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I have following problem: I developed an app in libgdx in eclipse. There was a problem with `Gdx.files.internal()` function, it threw file not found, but I searched it up and fixed by going into `Run Configurations` in eclipse, `Arguments` tab and picking `Other` in `Working Directory` section. Then I chose the assets folder and it worked. But I have the same problem now when I tried to export executable jar from eclipse. I guess that changed working directory isn't exported somehow, any ideas?
Btw, here's the stack

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:98)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:75)
at local.bb.learn2.MainMenuScreen.<init>(MainMenuScreen.java:29)
at local.bb.learn2.MainMenuScreen.getInstance(MainMenuScreen.java:121)
at local.bb.learn2.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:61)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:702)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:96)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: uiskin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:77)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:700)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: uiskin.json (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:163)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:75)
    ... 8 more
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at local.bb.learn2.MainMenuScreen.render(MainMenuScreen.java:131)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
    at local.bb.learn2.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:68)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:223)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

PS I am sure that is the problem because I changed the run configurations in eclipse back to Default working directory and it threw the same stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some useful information [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application)

As I understand, you should set your working directory on run configuration.
If you have many modules, it's good to have one folder for all.

From you errors I can see that there is a problem in a uiskin.json file.
And LibGDX cannot parse it properly.
You should share it or try different file similar to that one.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. The problem is just I have a launch configuration, which is crucial for the app to work. And this launch configuration work when I run it in eclipse. But when I export runnable file from project and run it from the console it doesn't work.

Comment: So it means files are in wrong directory.
Are they packed within jar file or are on the same directory as jar file?

Comment: Thanks for Your help! :) You didn't solve the problem but you put me on the right direction to get the solution. The assets folder link in desktop app was somehow not ok and I solved the problem by removing it and then adding it again by `Link Source` in `Build Path` menu. Thanks again, cheers!!